# web2py: How to target a div using the response.menu

Tags: python, web2py

The A() helper can take a `cid` or `target` attribute to target a DIV to load content. Using the response.menu tuples, how can this be achieved?

```
response.menu = [
    (T('Home'), False, URL('default', 'index'), []),
    (T('Library'), False, None, [ 
        (T('Services'), False, URL('default', 'library.load', args=['service'], user_signature=True))
        ])
]
```

*edit:*

My ultimate goal is to load the page in library.load into a target div.

Answer (score 0):

I cheated with jQuery at index.html. I hope there is a way to inject the attribute at server level.

```
<script>
    var s = $(".dropdown-menu a:contains('Services')").attr( 'data-w2p_target','main_div_comp' );
    s.attr("data-w2p_method", "GET");
</script>
```